# Fetching data from Firebase cloud database and showing them with load more button (Pagination) Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I have tried with this approach but getting `Uncaught FirebaseError: Function Query.startAfter() requires a valid first argument, but it was undefined.` The `lastVisible` is getting the value on console. Here is the code:

```
function loadMoreButtonAction() {
  fetchRequest(true);
}

function fetchRequest(isFromLoadMore) {
    var table = document.getElementById("outputTableID");

  var lastVisible;
  var tableIndex;
  if (isFromLoadMore == false) {
    if (table.rows.length > 2) {
        resetTable(table);
    }

    var first = firestore.collection(parentNode).orderBy("serialNo").limit(5);
    first.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      // Get the last visible document
      lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1];
      console.log("lastVisible", lastVisible);
      tableIndex = querySnapshot.size;
      document.getElementById("wallpaperCount").innerHTML = 'Total Items: ' + tableIndex + '';
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var productItem = Object.create(wallpapers);
        productItem.nodeId = doc.id;
        productItem.serialNo = doc.data().serialNo;
        productItem.title = doc.data().title;
        productItem.downloadNumber = doc.data().downloadNumber;
        productItem.isPremimumItem = doc.data().isPremimumItem;
        productItem.wallpaper1125_2436ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper1125_2436ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2208ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2208ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2688ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2688ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper828_1792ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper828_1792ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper750_1334ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper750_1334ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper640_1136ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper640_1136ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper1125_2436Url = doc.data().wallpaper1125_2436Url;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2208Url = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2208Url;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2688Url = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2688Url;
        productItem.wallpaper828_1792Url = doc.data().wallpaper828_1792Url;
        productItem.wallpaper750_1334Url = doc.data().wallpaper750_1334Url;
        productItem.wallpaper640_1136Url = doc.data().wallpaper640_1136Url;
        productItem.wallpaper1125_2436ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper1125_2436ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2208ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2208ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2688ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2688ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper828_1792ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper828_1792ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper750_1334ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper750_1334ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper640_1136ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper640_1136ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper1125_2436FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper1125_2436FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2208FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2208FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2688FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2688FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper828_1792FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper828_1792FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper750_1334FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper750_1334FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper640_1136FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper640_1136FacebookPhotoID;

        var row = table.insertRow(2);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
        var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
        var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
        var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
        var cell11 = row.insertCell(10);
        cell1.innerHTML = productItem.serialNo;
        cell2.innerHTML = productItem.title;
        cell3.innerHTML = productItem.downloadNumber;
        cell4.innerHTML = productItem.isPremimumItem;
        appendImageOnCell(cell5, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper1125_2436Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell6, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper1242_2208Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell7, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper1242_2688Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell8, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper828_1792Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell9, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper750_1334Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell10, productItem.wallpaper640_1136Url);
        appendButtonOnCell(cell11, productItem);
      });
    });
  } else {
    var second = firestore.collection(parentNode).orderBy("serialNo").startAfter(lastVisible).limit(5);
    second.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      // Get the last visible document
      lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1];
      console.log("lastVisible", lastVisible);
      tableIndex = tableIndex + querySnapshot.size;
      document.getElementById("wallpaperCount").innerHTML = 'Total Items: ' + tableIndex + '';
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var productItem = Object.create(wallpapers);
        productItem.nodeId = doc.id;
        productItem.serialNo = doc.data().serialNo;
        productItem.title = doc.data().title;
        productItem.downloadNumber = doc.data().downloadNumber;
        productItem.isPremimumItem = doc.data().isPremimumItem;
        productItem.wallpaper1125_2436ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper1125_2436ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2208ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2208ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2688ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2688ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper828_1792ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper828_1792ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper750_1334ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper750_1334ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper640_1136ImgName = doc.data().wallpaper640_1136ImgName;
        productItem.wallpaper1125_2436Url = doc.data().wallpaper1125_2436Url;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2208Url = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2208Url;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2688Url = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2688Url;
        productItem.wallpaper828_1792Url = doc.data().wallpaper828_1792Url;
        productItem.wallpaper750_1334Url = doc.data().wallpaper750_1334Url;
        productItem.wallpaper640_1136Url = doc.data().wallpaper640_1136Url;
        productItem.wallpaper1125_2436ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper1125_2436ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2208ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2208ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2688ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2688ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper828_1792ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper828_1792ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper750_1334ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper750_1334ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper640_1136ImgStorageRef = doc.data().wallpaper640_1136ImgStorageRef;
        productItem.wallpaper1125_2436FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper1125_2436FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2208FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2208FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper1242_2688FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper1242_2688FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper828_1792FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper828_1792FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper750_1334FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper750_1334FacebookPhotoID;
        productItem.wallpaper640_1136FacebookPhotoID = doc.data().wallpaper640_1136FacebookPhotoID;

        var row = table.insertRow(tableIndex);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
        var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
        var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
        var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
        var cell11 = row.insertCell(10);
        cell1.innerHTML = productItem.serialNo;
        cell2.innerHTML = productItem.title;
        cell3.innerHTML = productItem.downloadNumber;
        cell4.innerHTML = productItem.isPremimumItem;
        appendImageOnCell(cell5, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper1125_2436Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell6, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper1242_2208Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell7, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper1242_2688Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell8, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper828_1792Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell9, "./utilities/images/tick.png"); //productItem.wallpaper750_1334Url
        appendImageOnCell(cell10, productItem.wallpaper640_1136Url);
        appendButtonOnCell(cell11, productItem);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

My UI:
[image]

And this is the error I am getting:
[image]

Comment: See the Firebase documentation on [Paginate data with query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

Comment: Hello Sir, I have tried with the help of the document but my `lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1];` is not getting value properly I think. What am I missing here? I have updated my question.
Thanks!

Comment: The query itself looks good at first glance. Is there a way you can show the problem in code so that we can see it? Since we can't see your UI, it is often best if you can `console.log` the problematic value (like the `serialNo`) and then include the updated code and its output in the question.

Comment: I have update my code sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `lastVisible` is `undefined`, which is not allowed. When looking at your code, that makes sense, since you define `lastVisible` inside the `fetchRequest` function. So each time you call `fetchRequest`, you end up with a new `lastVisible` variable with an initial value of `undefined`.

You'll want to declare `lastVisible` outside of the `fetchRequest` method, so that its value is kept between calls to `fetchRequest`.

It also seems that you're duplicating **a lot** of code in `fetchRequest`. If we simplify this code and pull out the `lastVisible` variable, we end up with something like:

```
var lastVisible; // declare outside of fetchRequest so that its value is retained between calls
function fetchRequest(isFromLoadMore) {
  var query = firestore.collection(parentNode).orderBy("serialNo").limit(5);
  if (isFromLoadMore == false) {
    if (table.rows.length > 2) {
        resetTable(table);
    }
  }
  else if (lastVisible) {
    query = query.startAfter(lastVisible);
  }
  query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    // Get the last visible document
    lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1];
    console.log("lastVisible", lastVisible);

    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. <3 Now It's working exactly as I wanted. Stay safe stay blessed. :)

Comment: Sir, How can I fetch the latest/last entry with this `limit()` query? In real time database it has `limit_to_last`, but in Cloud data base, how can I fetch that? With the above approach it is always showing first top 5 entry (according to serial number). If I press load more then it is adding more 5 entry on top of existing entry list. But what I want is that first it will show the last 5 entry, then by pressing load more, next last 5 entry will be added at the bottom of those existing 5 entry. And it will go like that. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: To get the last  items, reverse the sort order and then use `limit` as you do now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added "Desc" like tthis: `firestore.collection(parentNode).orderBy("serialNo", "desc").limit(20);` and reverse my snapshot array like this `querySnapshot.reverse(); ` just before iterating the values, `querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>` but nothing is appearing on my table.

Comment: I recommend creating a new question for that problem. Please in there try to reproduce the problem with only hard-coded inputs, and only `console.log` outputs - as it's hard for us to see your table.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly instead of doing `productItem.title = doc.data().title;` and calling `doc.data()` a thousand times for every single possible field, you could just do:

```js
let productItemLiteral = { nodeId: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
let productItem = Object.create(wallpapers, productItemLiteral);
```

And with regards to the pagination, you can paginate your fetches with query cursors. The firestore documentation handles this area very well: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Basically, your fetch function could look like this:

```js
const fetchRecords = cursor => {
  const queryObj = cursor ?
    firestore().collection(parentNode).orderBy("serialNo").startAfter(cursor).limit(1 
 0)
    :
    firestore().collection(parentNode).orderBy("serialNo").limit(10);
  queryObj.get().then((querySnapshot => {
    // Save the last document to a global variable so you can use it as reference to fetch the next page
    lastDocCursor = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
    // Include the rest of your handler
  }
}

You should have a global variable: `lastDocCursor` initialized as `null`, so you could just call `fetchRecords(lastDocCursor);`. If a cursor already exists, it will fetch the next 10 documents that follow that document, if not, it will fetch the first 10
```